# Use temperature sensor for realtime data sync

Tags: windows-phone-8, xamarin, iot

I am planning to build an app that uses my device's temperature sensor to send realtime data inputs to cloud, bu tI am not able to find useful resources  regarding the same.
Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Have you taken a look at Bluemix IoT service?  It will allow you to send data from an IoT device into the cloud.  Here is a tutorial: j http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/iot-mobile-phone-iot-device-bluemix-apps-trs/index.html

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There are tons of framework platforms to do so like IBMs:

1. [octoblu](https://www.octoblu.com/) by Citrix
2. [mbed](https://www.mbed.com/en/) by ARM
3. flow+[M2X](https://m2x.att.com/) from ATT (they could work together although M2X will do the job)

Just to name few.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12624155)

Comment: How come it does not? He is looking for resources did you even look at the frameworks for IoT I suggested? There are tons of resources for IoT applications like the one planned.